# MVC3 return a File always in a new tab without replace the old one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file, pdf, tabs

I have a form with target="_blank" that posts, process and return a PDF File in a new tab, the problem is:

When I do first time, it's all OK, but when i do again, instead of opening a new tab, it replaces the old one with the new content!

And if i'm using Internet Explorer, it posts my parameters null, in this case I need to close the new tab, and do it again

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SubmitReport(string parameter)
{
   // all the code
   return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitReport", "ResumoPagamentos", FormMethod.Post, new { area = "CI3S", @target = "_Blank" }))
{
  // etc.. etc...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML `target` values are case-sensitive.

`_Blank` (capital `B`) is not the special `_blank` value (which always opens a new tab), but a tab named `_Blank`, which will be reused if it exists.

Comment: thanks, solved my problem! i didn't know this values were case sensitive!

Answer (score 0):

First create a hyperlink to open the appropriate file
clicking on the hyperlink will result in opening the pdf file in a new tab of browser

```
public ActionResult OpenFile(int id)
{
    var Filename = objdb.Pdfs.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.PdfFile).FirstOrDefault();
    if (Filename != null)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("/FileStorage/" + Filename);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=something.pdf");
            return File(path, Filename);
            //return File(path, "multipart/mixed", Filename);
            //return File(path, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```